# How to sum the results of a count that are beneath a specified value?

Tags: sql

For example I have a table called Cities:

```
+----+----------+  
| ID |   City   |  
+----+----------+  
| 1  | New York |  
|  2 | Chicago  |  
|  3 | Seattle  |  
|  4 | New York |  
+----+----------+
```

When I use the query:

```
SELECT Cities.city, Count(Cities.City) AS CitiesCount
FROM Cities
GROUP BY Cities.city;
```

My results are:

```
+----------+-------------+
|   City   | CitiesCount |
+----------+-------------+
| Chicago  |           1 |
| New York |           2 |
| Seattle  |           1 |
+----------+-------------+
```

What I am trying to do is have it sum all results where CitiesCount = 1 into an 'other' row, as shown below

```
+----------+-------------+
|   City   | CitiesCount |
+----------+-------------+
| New York |           2 |
| Other    |           2 |
+----------+-------------+
```

I believe I will need to use Unions or sub-queries to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select (case when cnt = 1 then 'others' else city end), sum(cnt)
from (select city, count(*) as cnt
      from table t1
      group by city
     ) t
group by (case when cnt = 1 then 'others' else city end);
```

Comment: @Blorgbeard. . . Yes OP wants count where as count as `1` grouping as `others`.

Comment: My comment was referring to the [first revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55128202/1)